# Kubernetes Jobs not Completing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

Follwing the documentation and provided example here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job

I run `kubectl apply -f job.yaml`

```
kubectl apply -f job.yaml                                    
job.batch/pi created
```

Monitoring the job with get pods `pi-fts6q                   1/2     Running   0          52s`

I always see 1/2 Running even after the job is complete and checking the logs shows it is completed.

How can I get the job to show a completed status?  The job will stay in a running state showing no completions forever.

```
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Thu, 06 Jun 2019 16:21:36 -0500
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

It seems the underlying pod that did the work completed, but the actual job-controller stays alive forever.

Comment: Found the answer, I'm running an istio proxy envoy: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in incomplete implementation of proxy-agent.

Simply add a **'/quitquitquit'** handler to proxy-agent.

Users can manually add a curl or http request to localhost to stop sidecar when the job is done. P0 is a workaround.

More information you can find here: [`istio-issue`](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324)

Answer (score 1):

I just added these two curls at the end of the script of the job to kill istio and the pilot:

```
curl --request POST localhost:15000/quitquitquit || echo 'No istio it is then'
curl --request POST localhost:15020/quitquitquit || echo 'No istio at all, not even pilot'
```